# Java Subclass error: No enclosing instance of type is accesible

Tags: java, class, subclass, hierarchy

I'm attempting to create a class Person with a subclass Employee, and I get No enclosing of type error. I've tried to google how basic classes and sub classes are portrayed and it's always 'simple' the same way I write it so I'm probably mistaking something else.

Minimal as I understand, as requested.

```
import com.Person.Employee;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Employee test = new Employee();

    }
}
package com;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    public Person() {
        name = "";
}
public class Employee extends Person {
    private float personalID;

        public Employee(){
        super();
        personalID = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

error: No enclosing instance of type Person is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Person (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Person)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Java sorry sorry.

Comment: Present a [mre], and also the literal text of the error message you receive.  The message paraphrase you've given seems to indicate that you have made `Employee` an inner class of some other class (possibly, but not necessarily, `Person`), but that is not reflected in the code presented.  If indeed you have done that, then it is probably inappropriate.

Comment: Did you try using the keyword “extends”? “ Emlpoyee extends Person”, this is how you declare a daughter class from its parent class. And normally I would write the employee class and person class as two separate java file both inside the com package. I have never seen a class written within another one

Comment: Hello, the extend was in the original and the error persists. I did not know that I was supposed to use two files. I'm following an online course. I'm gonna test that.

Comment: You were right. It was solved by making it a new file. Thank you. .